# Unit Test Code Coverage for a Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, qunit, blanket.js

I have several QUnit tests running successfully for our extension.

I'd like to gather code coverage information, and thought I would use blanket.js to do so.

However, when I click the 'Enable coverage' button, I see several CSP violation messages in the JavaScript Console:

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'
```

I've tried updating the content security policy of the extension, adding 'unsafe-inline' and 'unsafe-eval'.  With the 'unsafe-inline', Chrome doesn't load the extension.  And the 'unsafe-eval' option doesn't fix the problem.

Below is the snippet of CSP from my manifest.json file:

```
"content_security_policy": "default-src  'unsafe-inline' 'self'"
```

Is there a way to get blanket.js to run successfully for a Chrome extension?

If not, is there an alternative to blanket.js for Chrome extensions?

I'm currently using:

Chrome 34
 blanket - v1.1.5
 QUnit v1.10.0

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Partial answer: quoting Chrome docs, "There is no mechanism for relaxing the restriction against executing inline JavaScript. In particular, setting a script policy that includes 'unsafe-inline' will have no effect." So you cannot bypass no-inline constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing the implementation of `_addScript` to:

```
function(data) {
    (1,eval)(data);
}
```

And adding `'unsafe-eval'` to your CSP.

Comment: Excellent.  That works! At least I get code coverage results.  I still get a single CSP Violation message in the console.

Comment: I was able to fix the second CSP violation, by commenting out  line (4654) in the blanket.js file:    

//body.appendChild(script); 

and replacing it with :

    (1,eval)(script.text);